# Improper Syntax while using vuex mapState as a Computed Value

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to use vuex. If I include the mapState computed value as follows on its own, the syntax is correct.

```
 computed: mapState({
  userName: state => state.userName
 })
```

However, I have other computed values used in my component. Thus, if I try to include it within the same block with the other computed values as follows, the syntax is no longer accepted.

```
 computed: {
  routerprops () {
  ...
  },
  mapState({
   userName: state => state.userName
  }) 
 }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It should be `...mapState(` in the second example (Spread the object properties inside the `computed` object you wrapped it with). The docs contain an [example showing just that](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#object-spread-operator)

Comment: Thank you blex, the dots have solved the syntax issue. However, I am not sure I understand what you mean by spreading the object properties.

Comment: Thank you again blex!

Comment: The three dots are the [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). When used on an Object, it "extracts" every property in that object (the one returned by `mapState()` in your case), and adds them to the object around it (`computed`, in your case)

Comment: Yes, got it! Thanks again.